Different nugets restored on the same solution on different platforms
Platform:

Windows 10
Visual Studio 2022
.NET Core 3.1
C#

I have a small solution containing an executable (console application) as a start-up project and several class libraries projects.
Whenever I build the solution using the Visual Studio build (msbuild) - along with the nuget packages that the projects consume, there are additional infrastructure/SDK/FW such as System and  System.Runtime namespace nugets restored to the default nuget cache folder. There are about 50 additional nuget packages.
Whenever I'm running a CLI command of dotnet build or event publish on the solution, but on a different platform (but also Windows), these additional nuget packages are not restored.
Trying to figure out 2 things:

What is the reason for the restore of these nuget packages?
How can I create the same nuget repository containing these nuget packages on the second platform?


THe machine that is downloading fewer packages probably has a "fallback folder" that has the other packages already locally.  You can remove this variable by having a nuget.config file that clears the fallback folders config (see the nuget.config reference documentation)

@zivkan - Thanks, In my cli publish command, I'm using a nuget.config file as a source for the nugets. I'll look in the documentation
